# Convergence of $\int_1^\infty x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi x} \, dx$ where $s\in\mathbb C$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

The "Riemann's functional equation" section of the Wikipedia article on the Riemann zeta function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) states that
$$I=\displaystyle\int_1^\infty x^{\frac{s}{2}-1}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi x} \, dx$$
is convergent for all complex $s$.
My result yields that it diverges for $s=2$.
Since
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi x}\le\dfrac{1}{x}$$
for $x\ge 0$, $I$ diverges if
$$J=\displaystyle\int_1^\infty x^{\frac{s}{2}-2} \, dx$$
diverges, which it does when $s=2$:
$$J(2)=\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \dfrac{dx}{x}\to\infty .$$
Why should $I$ be convergent for all complex $s$?

Comment: Have you a link for the Wikipedia article?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

Comment: For $s=2$ the integral provides something positive and bounded by $\frac{\zeta(2)}{\pi}$, so it does not diverge. You tacitly assumed that $\frac{1}{x}$ is the best possible bound for $\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-n^2\pi x}$, which is not the case.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Thanks. How should I prove the convergence, then? Also, how did you get the bound $\frac{\zeta (s)}{\pi}$?

Comment: So, it's bounded **above** by a divergent integral. Well, every integral is. If you could bound it **below** by a positive divergent integral, you then should be worried.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi x} = O(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx}) =O(\frac1{e^x-1}) = O(e^{-x/2})$ that is it has exponential decay at $\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n^2 \pi x}$ with $x \geq 1$ can be easily majorized:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n^2 \pi x} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-k \pi x},$$
since every term is nonegative.
 On the other hand $e^{-k \pi x} = (e^{-\pi x})^k$, so 
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-k \pi x} = \frac{e^{-\pi x}}{1 - e^{-\pi x}}$. Now the modulus of the integrand can be majorized by the nonnegative function $g_s(x)=x^{\frac{s}{2}-1} \cdot \frac{e^{-\pi x}}{1 - e^{-\pi x}}$ with $s \in R$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty} g_s(x) dx < \infty $ for every $s \in R$, thanks to the exponential in the numerator; please observe that the exponential in the denominator does not play any role since the denominator ranges between $1 - e^{-\pi}$ and $1$  (therefore it is bounded away from zero) as $x$ ranges in $[1,\infty]$. Now the general case $s \in C$ comes easily.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\exp(-n^2\pi x)$ tends to zero rapidly
as $x\to\infty$, Its first term is $\exp(-\pi x)$ and the sum of the remaining
terms is $o(\exp(-\pi x))$. As this has exponential decay, so does $x^t f(x)$
for any real $x$, and so $\int_1^\infty x^t f(x)\,dx$ is a convergent integral.

Answer (score 1):

A sufficient bound for proving the convergence derives from the following **Lemma**: for a positive integer $N$, the number of representations of $N$ as a sum of three integer squares is bounded by $CN$ for an absolute constant $C$. **Proof**: we want an upper bound for the number $r_3(N)$ of lattice points on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=N$ with radius $\sqrt{N}$. If we center a ball with radius $\frac{1}{2}$ at every lattice point, these balls are disjoint and their union does not cover more than the spherical shell between the radii $\sqrt{N}-\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sqrt{N}+\frac{1}{2}$. It follows that
$$ r_3(N)\cdot\frac{\pi}{6}\leq \frac{4\pi}{3}\left[\left(\sqrt{N}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^3-\left(\sqrt{N}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\right] $$
so $r_3(N)\leq 24N+2$ and $C=25$ is an effective choice.

<sup>Actually the constant $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ above can be lowered by solving a complex sphere-packing-in-a-spherical-shell problem, but this is both fairly difficult and fairly irrelevant for the problem at hand. I believe that the optimal constant is $\frac{4\pi^2}{9\sqrt{3}}$, leading to an improved $C=15$.</sup>

---

By setting $f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-n^2\pi x}$ it follows that
$$ f(x)^3 \leq 1+\sum_{N\geq 1}CN e^{-\pi N x}=1+\frac{C e^{\pi x}}{(e^{\pi x}-1)^2} $$
so
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} e^{-\pi n^2 x}\leq \frac{1}{2}\left[\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{Ce^{\pi x}}{(e^{\pi x}-1)^3}}-1\right].$$
The RHS decays like $e^{-\pi x/3}$ as $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: Very interesting. But where does the factor of $\frac{\pi}{6}$ come from?

Comment: @Tu1: $\frac{\pi}{6}$ is the volume of a ball with radius $\frac{1}{2}$.